# Solr Wildcards Scoring and NGramFIlterFactory

Tags: java, solr, solrj

When searching in Solr with wildcards, documents seem not to get a score.
Consider I have the following documents containing first names in my index and indexed them in this order:

1. Michael
2. Michaelson
3. Michael

Searching for the first name "Michael*" and limiting the result size to 2 gives me the first two back. But obviously Person 3 fits my search better than Person 2. What should I do here? Can I solve this problem by using NGramFilterFactory and omitting wildcards?

Comment: first do a exact match...if your get lesser results then go for the wildcard search

Comment: Have two fields, one for scoring exact matches and one for the ngramfiltered results.

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti how can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this kind of problem, which is pretty similar to an autocomplete problem by copying your field "first_name" into others field with analyzers that can be based on EdgeNGramFilterFactory and will index:
M
Mi
Mic
Mich
Micha
Michae
Michael

Using:

```xml
<field name="first_name" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false"/>
<copyField source="first_name" dest="textnge"/>
<field name="textnge" type="autocomplete_edge" indexed="true" stored="false" />
<field name="textng" type="autocomplete_ngram" indexed="true" stored="false" />
```

and

```xml
    <fieldType name="autocomplete_edge" class="solr.TextField">
        <analyzer type="index">
            <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>
            <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="([\.,;:-_])" replacement=" " replace="all"/>
            <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" maxGramSize="30" minGramSize="1"/>
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
            <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>
            <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
    <fieldType name="autocomplete_ngram" class="solr.TextField">
        <analyzer type="index">
            <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" maxGramSize="20" minGramSize="1"/>
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
            <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="0" generateNumberParts="0" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="0"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

Then you could configure your query handler like this:

```xml
  <requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="defType">edismax</str>
      <str name="qf">first_name^30 textnge^100.0 textng^20.0</str>
    </lst>
```

So that exact matching weighs more that partial matching, and edge from the first word also weighs more than a partial match on another word.

Comment: Im using complexphrase. I cant find any results anymore if I search for partstrings now.

Comment: Added another analyzer for matching words that are beyond the first

Comment: Works! Thanks for you answer. i marked it as correct. Do you have an idea how to fix this issue too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67191819/solr-shorter-fields-score-higher