# Solr shorter fields score higher

Tags: java, solr, lucene, solrj

I have the following case with 3 documents containing the following first names:

1. Müller
2. Müllermann
3. Müller
   They are stored in a textfield.

Searching partial for the String "Mülle" and limiting the returnsize to 2 I would expect that 1. and 3. get returned but not 2 because its longer. But the score for all of them is the same.
Query:

```
rows=2&fl=*&q=_query_:"{!complexphrase+df%3Dname}Mülle"+OR+_query_:"{!complexphrase+df%3Dname_exakt}Mülle"&fq=(quelle:GP)&sort=score+DESC
```

Comment: Token length isn't taken into consideration for scoring. If you want to add a certain boost based on shorter content, add a second field that contains the field length and use that for boosting as well.

Comment: Ok I see. Sounds comprehensible. Can you give an example how to do that?

Comment: There's an update request processor made for that kind of usage: https://solr.apache.org/docs/8_8_0//solr-core/org/apache/solr/update/processor/FieldLengthUpdateProcessorFactory.html - you either add a clone update processor that copies the same content into a different field name first (or submit the same text content for both fields). The update processor then replaces the content with a numeric value representing the text length before being sent to Solr. Be aware that this is in regards to the _whole field_, and not single tokens.

Comment: If you want to do it for single tokens, you'll might have to look into payloads and the payload scorer and do it that way instead.

Comment: If trying to match a specific field containing first name only (ie. not a general text field), and if the field is normalized, then the token length should be taken into account for scoring. The parameter 'omitNorms' defaults to true for primitive types, so a string field for example would require `omitNorms=false`.